# Next JS dynamic routing not working on export production static build

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm building an app with Next. using nested dynamic routing. In development mode, everything works as expected. But when I deploy the app in production ,When you hit reload (like F5) it gives you 404

use next version : `9.5.2`

my directory structure is like this:

```
pages
 -users
    -[page]
        - [id].tsx
        - index.tsx
    -index.tsx
```

Here's how I link to the dynamic page:

```
<Link href='/users/[page]/[id]' as='/users/edit/${id}'>
<a>Edit</a> </Link>
```

Here sample code user/[page]/[id].tsx

```
class User extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
     super(props);  
     this.state = {
     },
  }; 
 static getInitialProps({query}) {
   return {query}
 }
  async componentDidMount(){
     const { query } = this.props;
      if(query?.id){
         await this.props.getUserById(query?.id);
      }
  }
}
```

Here static build command

```
`npm run export`
```

Here [static build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UnINj.png)

my build is a set of HTML, js, css assets I hosted on the web server (Apache, Nginx).

If I clicked in link users from index.tsx page, my URL look '/users/edit/1/' and work fine, but if I refresh the page I get error 404. In the development mode refresh page, everything works fine.
I am stuck on this problem for many days. Do u know how I can fix this?

Comment: you need to use `exportPathMap` for generating a know number of pages. see https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export#caveats

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution for using dynamic paths in production without static export?